# Add Authenticator for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, authenticator

Is there a way to achieve SSO in Xamarin forms app. I have done some basic research and have zeroed down on 2 approaches for Authenticating my enterprise apps.

1.) Use **microsoft company portal intune**. For this I would be creating a new sample app, registering it in Azure AD, configure InTunes in Azure, installing Microsoft Authenticator,use InTune nuget packages for Xamarin forms side of code.
For this do we have any steps on how to achieve the same or some head way, regarding app registration and configuration in InTune, configuration of new URI for app, code changes at App end, in order to invoke Authenticator, code snippets for Xamarin Forms and not for Native apps.

2.) **Leverage Service Broker**. I had found [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/leveraging-brokers-on-Android-and-iOS) link, which expands on the same, but could not get any ADAL DLL's to achieve the same.

So do we have any concrete or recommended approaches in achieving SSO with microsoft authenticators for Xamarin Forms Apps, would be glad to know more.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: Hey thanks for this. Seems like a good start for me, reading the description. Also do we have any code snippets on achieving the on-behalf-of flow code logic for OAuth 2.0 with Azure AD, for service to service calls?.